# In Java, Is it Possible to Have Two Functions with the Exact Same Signature, Except One is static

Tags: java, generics, overloading, static-methods

I am writing a class `Baz<T>` with function declarations similar to the following:

```
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T);                               // Overload #1
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>);                // Overload #2
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>, SomeClass1<T>); // Overload #3
```

Since #1 is the only function that uses `this`, I could make all the others `static`:

```
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T);
public static <T> SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>);             //#2 and #3 now static
public static <T> SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>, SomeClass1<T>);
```

However, that would make calling different `foo` overloads inconsistent. I could simply make #1 take a `Baz` (instead of `this`), but it seems that:

```
baz.foo(t);
```

is more syntactic sugar than:

```
Baz.foo(baz, t);
```

If I don't make #2 and #3 static, then there is no way to prevent something like:

```
Baz<Bar> baz1 = new Baz<Bar>(); // Bar is any class type; replaces T
Baz<Bar> baz2 = new Baz<Bar>();

SomeClass1<Bar> sc = new SomeClass1<Bar>(baz1); // make a SomeClass1 that is somehow attached to baz1; however, SomeClass1 does NOT keep a reference to baz1

baz2.foo(new Bar(), sc); // runs and compiles just fine!
```

What I ended up trying to do was to have a non-static and a static overload for each one, where the non-static overloads simply delegate to the static:

```
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T);                 // All non-static overloads delegate to the corresponding static overload
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>);             
public SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>, SomeClass1<T>);

public static <T> SomeClass1<T> foo(T, Baz<T>);     // Baz could be first or last argument
public static <T> SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>);            
public static <T> SomeClass1<T> foo(T, SomeClass1<T>, SomeClass1<T>);
```

I get the following error coming from the declaration of overload #2, #3, and their corresponding static overloads, replacing `my-method-signature` with the corresponding method signature and `my-class-name` with `Baz<T>`, or the data type I am using:

> Erasure of method my-method-signature is the same as another method in type my-class-name

**Questions:**

1. Is there any better option than what I am trying or want to do? Is it possible to accomplish what I am attempting? If so, how?
2. Is what I am trying to do (i.e., make syntax consistent and make it impossible to call a method with "mismatching" `SomeClass1<T>` and `this` objects) even worth it?

P.S. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Why are you worried about making static a method that *can* be static? Why not just leave it non static and move on?

Comment: @Bohemian because then that allows users to call a function on a certain object when it doesn't even operate on that object.

Comment: This link could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185449/static-and-non-static-methods-with-the-same-name-in-parent-class-and-implementin. Also note that in some cases using `static` methods is generally an anti-pattern. Try to make things simple as possible.

Comment: I find your question rather confusing. At one point you say you want to prevent `baz2.foo(new Bar(), sc);`, and then you proceed to try to declare _both_ a non-static and static `foo`, which doesn't prevent that at all...

Comment: @Sweeper I was trying to prevent that by offering an alternative option, yet still be consistent with other syntax. I did not know that a static function could be called with an object when I wrote this.

Comment: @HarryCoder Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a better option: Do nothing.

There is nothing wrong with having a method that doesn’t need `this` to do its job. That’s an implementation choice, which has nothing to do with an instance fulfilling its contract of implementing methods.

There are plenty of commonly used design patterns that have such methods. Take the various factory patterns for example - their methods have a contract to return an instance. Nobody knows or cares if they use `this` to get the job done or not.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

> 8.4.2. Method Signature Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters
> (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N
> to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
> method m2 if either:
>
> m2 has the same signature as m1, or
>
> the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature
> of m2.
>
> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1
> is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.
>
> It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with
> override-equivalent signatures in a class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4